# Why won't my Sony a350 take a picture in low light situations?

Tags: low-light, night, sony-alpha

I'm trying to take a photo with my Sony a350 but it won't take pictures in low light situations. I have fiddled around with the shutter speed and the aperture but it still won't take the picture! (very frustrating)

Basically I'm trying to take a picture of a lit pergola at night, but it won't work.

Comment: Can you provide more information? What mode are you using, are you using auto focus?

Comment: Probably Michael Clark has hit the nail on the head with his answer. With regard to "fiddling" with shutter speed and aperture, that sounds like a recipe for further frustration. If you don't know what you're doing with exposure settings, I would highly recommended spending the little time necessary learning about exposure and the connection between aperture, shutter speed and ISO settings and their effects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using manual focus. There probably is not enough light for your camera's auto focus system to work properly.